# GWT Formpanel POST issue

Tags: servlets, gwt

I am using GWT FormPanel to submit a POST request to a servlet which renders a pdf. The screen I am using to post have got a pop up with yes, no and preview button. yes and preview would open a pdf in new tab in browser.

The problem is when I use IE11 and clicks on preview it opens up a pdf well, I dont close the tab go back to previous screen and clicks yes, again request reaches to servlet but this time all the request parameters are null.

If the pdf tab is closed and then I click on yes it again works fine. This is an issue with IE11, works fine with Chrome. Any Ideas ?

If I change it to GET it works fine but I have a huge data that needs to be passed to servlet.

here is a code snippet :

```
      formPanel.setBodyBorder(false);
      formPanel.setBorders(false);
      formPanel.setHeaderVisible(true);
      formPanel.setAction(someURL+ "/someServlet");
      formPanel.setMethod(Method.POST);
      formPanel.setTarget("somePDF");
      formPanel.setId("report");


      HiddenField<String> hddnF = new HiddenField<String>();
      hddnF.setName("Yogi");
      hddnF.setValue("Value is set...");
      formPanel.add(hddnF);
      formPanel.submit();
```

Have overridden setTarget to show result(pdf) into new popup/tab

```
public native void setTarget(String target)/*-{
        this.@com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.FormPanel::setTarget(Ljava/lang/String;)(target);
    }-*/;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, sounds like a decent question but maybe break up that block paragraph a bit, to make it more understandable where the error happens.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, Hope the snippet is now readable.

Comment: just an update - After the preview is clicked and pdf is opened, i click on yes, and it just refreshes the page. The request does reaches to a servlet but as a GET and since I am not appending any query params to it everything is null. Also look at the setTarget above. looks like IE11 when sees a frame already opened it just refreshes it instead looking for the method assosciated with it (GET or POST),  Can anyone suggest me a hack to overcome this issue.